# Adding texture to the model, getting a pink model

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, uv

Can you explain please how to activate a texture on a model? I have both but all I could achive is a pink model. I am a web developer trying to build a game and my final goal is to render 8-direction isometric unit sprites, but obviously can not achieve this without a texture. I am a newbie in Blender.

[The link to the model is here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/oyexk91drjkmwe8/lumberjack.zip/file)

[image: My Result]

Comment: Maybe you forgot to create a material, and assign it to the model? The model is already unwrapped, so the only cause seems to be the material absence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a material. There are few in the file, but they are not for Cycles. Open Material tab in the property panel, and create one. Hit "Use nodes", then in the Node editor add a "Texture/Image texture", and set the image file in this texture node. Then play with the shader settings.
[image: material needed screen]

Comment: Can you please give a more detailed explanation to what should happen after you hit "Use nodes"? I see this and am kinda lost.  https://i.imgur.com/Dm1xqJO.png On your screenshot there is a png connected to the Base Color somehow

Comment: Okay, I have moved forward to this, but still no luck https://i.imgur.com/DuOQbMc.png

Comment: Now I got it, there was ANOTHER material on top of this one, now it works, thank you for your answer and your time digging into the question :)